# How does Stripe conceal data input by users into Stripe-element objects?

Tags: stripe-payments

```
var stripeElements = function (publicKey, setupIntent) {
  var stripe = Stripe(publicKey);
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Element styles
  var style = {
    base: {
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily:
        '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
      },
    },
  };

  var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
  console.log(card); // returns a "t" object

  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Element focus ring
  card.on('focus', function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('card-element');
    el.classList.add('focused');
  });

  card.on('blur', function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('card-element');
    el.classList.remove('focused');
  });

  // Handle payment submission when user clicks the pay button.
  var button = document.getElementById('submit');
  button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeLoadingState(true);
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    stripe
      .confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: { email: email },
        },
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          changeLoadingState(false);
          var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          // The PaymentMethod was successfully set up
          orderComplete(stripe, setupIntent.client_secret);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

Stripe uses the above stripe.confirmCardSetup method to create a setupIntent object. This object can be used later to issue a charge.

In the above example, a Stripe "element" is used to create a "card" (the credit card) input. After I submit this info., this card-element gets attached to the object passed into the stripe.confirmCardSetup method, but when I attempt to console log the card object and find the CC data that was just input, I don't see it and I've been through every attribute.

How does Stripe conceal this info.?

Comment: hi, when you say "but when I attempt to console log the card and find the data that was just input", could you describe more? What exactly are you logging, and what are you expecting to see in your browser logs?

Comment: console.log(card); // returns a "t" object; all I meant was the card object doesn't include the CC data so how is it passed?

Comment: the `card` that you're logging, that isn't an actual "Card" object on Stripe, that is the Card Element (an HTML Element), as you're creating `var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });` in your code. What represents the card object in Stripe is the `payment_method` under the SetupIntent. Try logging that out.

Comment: So the card object acts like an iframe, back to Stripe itself?

Comment: correct! That is the intended behavior, so your code/server doesn't touch any of your customer's card details, for PCI compliance

Comment: Awesome, thank you for clarifying.